# How to hide anchor tag when data is not actually bind to the variable in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a service request to retrieve data from yelp api. After I hit the search button, the service call is processing so it take about 2 sec to get a respond. Here is my html:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{businessAddress}}</td>
    <td>{{display_phone}}</td>
    <td><a ng-href="{{website}}">Yelp Review Page</a></td>
</tr>
```

Because the website url is really long so I wrapped it into an `<a>` tag.

Now the issue is the `<a>` tag shows up even before the respond was received, so it looks a little bit annoying.
See the screen shots below:

[image]

[image]

The first screen shot is taken when it is loading waiting for respond from the server. The second shot is when everything is loaded.

How do I get rid of the "Yelp Review Page" in the first screen shot? In another words, I do not want to display anything unless the actual data is received.

Comment: Seems like digest cycle is not getting run..How you are getting data from service? using jQuery ajax?

Comment: why not `<a ng-href="{{website}}" ng-show="website">`?

Comment: @Daniel This solved the problem. Why don't you put it as an answer with explaination of why it works, so i can accept the answer for future user reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a ng-href="{{website}}" ng-show="website">`

This will make sure that the element is not visible until `website` variable is initialized.

Comment: Try this in your console: `var str = ''; if (str) console.log('true'); if (!str) console.log('false')`;. You'll see that an empty string returns false and that's why it works even if you initialize the var the way you did.

Comment: My mistake, I was not initialize the `website` variable. Sorry about the confusion